# How to separate values from xml tags into a new line in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I tried with .query('data(/content/value)') but it just puts all the values into one row whereas I am looking for displaying it in a different row.

My XML results are attached

[image]

Any help on the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems want :

```
select t.value ('.', 'INT')
from @xml.nodes ('./content/value') as spt(t);
```